# Keep Checking A Value Without Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

For a small C# Windows forms project I'm working on, I need to ask a simple Y/N question. I need it to repeat until it is given the correct value. If I use this code, it creates a stack overflow:

```
    void Intro()
    {

        if (input == "YES" || input == "Y")
        {
          //Do Stuff
        }
        else
        { 
            Intro();
        }
    }
```

I looked around and apparently the best way to handle this is with a while loop. So I try using this code, which results in the form not loading when I compile and run:

```
    void Intro()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (input == "YES" || input == "Y")
            {
              //Do Stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't give any errors, and runs until I stop it. The method is run right after InitializeComponent. This is probably a really stupid question, so sorry if it could be answered in a few seconds.

Comment: The first creates a `stack` to store the addresses of the last call before calling the next method, this stack has limited size and it will become `overflowed` by the code you provided. The second doesn't need any stack, it is just a loop running the same segment of code while the condition to loop is still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the checking in an event; it doesnt necessarily have to be a button click event.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(input=="YES" || input=="Y")
        //do stuff
     else
        //reshow question
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first one you are calling a kind of an endless recursive method(a method that calls itself) which causes the stack to overflow.

However in the second method there is a single method which is called once and in that method a loop is called.

When loop goes for next iteration the previous iteration is closed which do not causes the stack to overflow.

Oh BTW, you are missing `break` keywork in loop.

```
void Intro()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (input == "YES" || input == "Y")
        {
          //Do Stuff
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, the OPs need some explanation about the difference between the first code and the second code, the first throws `StackOverflowException` while the second doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, but the form still doesn't appear.

Comment: is this method called in the constructor of the form?

Answer (score 1):

The first example created a stack overflow because input != Y, so it jumps to the else branch, which calls intro again, which calls intro again, which calls intro again, and so on. - this is the stack that overflows.

If the second loop is being activated when the form is instantiated, it will never make it out of the loop to actually show the form.

What you need to do even for a simple form like this is to rely on events to drive your logic. If input is referring to a textbox, then hook up to the `TextChanged` event. Forms are not intended to run endless loops as they will lock the UI unless they are run in a separate thread, which leads to additional complexity if you need to interact with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

**The first code** creates **recursion** and too many recursive calls fills the stack and you get the `StackOverFlowException`.

**The second code** contains an infinite loop that keeps executing the code with out any delay, so your application hangs out.

The right way to do this task:

```
void Intro()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (input == "YES" || input == "Y")
        {
          //Do Stuff
          break; //it will break the loop when you will get the correct value
        }
    }
}
```

Other wise it will keep executing the code whether you get the correct value or not.